# Performance in MVC web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, firebug, partial-views, performance-testing

I am struggling to get some performance in my MVC application.I am loading a partial page (popup) which is taking hardly 500ms. But each time the popup loads it also downloads 2 jQuery files as well. 
is it possible to use the jQuery from cache or from parent page?

I have attached the image in red which shows 2 additional request to server.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In order to improve the performance you can try with the following approaches:

1. see if your application server supports GZip and configure the application/server to return the responses always archived in Gzip
2. Use minified version of JQuery
3. there are also Packing libraries where you can pack all the imported resources, such as CSS files and JS files, and the browser will do only 1 request per resource type. For instance, in Java we have a library called packtag.

In general, I recommend you using Google Chrome browser and its performance analyzer. It will give you good hints.

Answer (score 1):

In the Bundle config use this code

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

and also indclude both files in single bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Does the popup use an iframe or does it's content just get added to the DOM of the current page?

If it gets added to the current page you could try just adding the script references to the parent page instead. It might not always be the best idea if the parent page has no need for those two files, but if the parent page also uses the jQuery validation then the popup will be able to use the parent's reference to the script file.

For an iframe I'd suggest looking at Gzip and minification to make the scripts load faster.

Comment: We are adding the popup to DOM element, i will try yo add reference of parent page, do you have any article , how to reference the parent page script to popup.

Comment: If the popup is just part of the parent's DOM, then it automatically has all the script references that the parent has, as well as any globally scoped javascript variables you've declared. Try to think of the popup as just another div on the page instead of thinking of it as an entirely different object.